# Odoo 13 - multiple model and menus in same module

Tags: odoo, odoo-view, odoo-13

I'm new to odoo and learning developing custom module. Trying to develop an contact management app for company and person. Following are the files and code structure:

```
#models.py
from odoo import models, fields, api


class company(models.Model):
    _name = 'cs_contact.company'
    _description = 'Model for create company profile.'

    name = fields.Char('Company name', required=True)
    country_id = fields.Many2one('res.country', string='Country', help='Select Country', ondelete='restrict', required=True)
    ho_address = fields.Text('HO address')
    website = fields.Char('Website')
    courier_account = fields.Char('Courier Account')
    email = fields.Char('Email')
    

class person(models.Model):
    _name = 'cs_contact.person'
    _description = 'Model for create person contact.'

    name = fields.Char('Full Name', required=True)
    country_id = fields.Many2one('res.country', string='Country', help='Select Country', ondelete='restrict', required=True)
    email = fields.Char('Email')
    im_id = name = fields.Char('Instant messaging ID (Skype/line)')
    worked_before = fields.Selection([
        ('Yes', 'Yes'),
        ('No', 'No'),
        ], string="Worked Before?")
    how_we_meet = fields.Selection([
        ('Fair', 'Fair'),
        ('Email', 'Email'),
        ('Agent', 'Agent'),
        ], string="How we meet?")
    quantity = fields.Integer(string='Quantity')
    note = fields.Text('Note')
```

Views looke like:

```
#views.xml
<odoo>
  <data>
    <!-- explicit list view definition -->

    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="cs_contact.list">
      <field name="name">cs_contact list</field>
      <field name="model">cs_contact.person</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree>
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="country_id" />
            <field name="email"/>
        </tree>
    </field>      
    </record>

    <record id="view_cs_contactsearch" model="ir.ui.view">                                
      <field name="name">cs_contact list</field>
      <field name="model">cs_contact.person</field>                            
      <field name="arch" type="xml">                                    
        <search string="Search contacts">                                        
          <field name="name"></field>                                        
          <field name="country_id"></field>                                        
          <field name="email"></field>
        </search>

      </field>   

    </record>

  </data>
</odoo>
```

Menu looks like:

```
#menu.xml
<odoo>
  <act_window  id="action_company" name=" Company Contacts" res_model="cs_contact.company" view_mode="tree,form"  />  

  <menuitem  id="contact_root" name="Contacts" sequence='-1' />
  <menuitem  id="contact_company" name="Company" parent="contact_root" action="action_company" sequence="-1" />

</odoo>
```

It's working fine for company contact. Now I'm not getting how to create top menu for person and define view. [This is the the design I want](https://prnt.sc/toc7lq). I tried various method from blogs but didn't work. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added `country_id` in `cs_contact.person` view definition but the field does not exist. Remove it from the view definition or declare it in the corresponding model.

To add the `Person` menu item next to the `Company` menu item, you just need to use the same parent and higher sequence number then connect it to the corresponding [action](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/actions.html#window-actions-ir-actions-act-window).

***Example:***

```xml
<act_window id="action_person" name="Persons" res_model="cs_contact.person" view_mode="tree,form"/>
<menuitem id="contact_person" name="Person" parent="contact_root" action="action_person" sequence="2"/>
```